# How do I get the id of a textbox that is invoking a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html

What I want is to get the id (i.e myHeader, myHeader2, etc.)

This is what I'm trying now,

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="myHeader" onblur="getValue(this)" />
<input type="text" id="myHeader2" onblur="getValue(this)" />
<input type="text" id="myHeader3" onblur="getValue(this)" />
<input type="text" id="myHeader4" onblur="getValue(this)" />
```

Javascript:

```
function getValue(obj){
    var someVar = document.getElementById(obj).value;
}
```

But I'm not getting anything, the event is not firing as well, how do I do this?

Comment: Why would you need to? You already have `obj` that should refer to the element, selecting it again is pointless.

Comment: `<input type="text" id="myHeader" onblur="getValue('myHeader')" />`

Comment: @onemach That's hardly a generic solution; you'd have to hardcode the function calls with the id on every single element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `obj` object already have `id` and `value` property:

```
function getValue(obj){
    alert('id - ' + obj.id);
    alert('value - ' + obj.value);
}
```

Note that when you pass `this` context to your function, you pass your DOM element. Not id. And you can operate with it already as with DOM element. No need for `document.getElementById`.

Comment: How can I do this in jQuery? it's the same?

Comment: In jquery you can pass DOM element `$(obj)` or id `$('#' + obj.id)`

Comment: Not worked because at this time function is undefined. See updated demo http://jsfiddle.net/antyrat/92WLE/1/

Comment: Ok, it's working, but why wasn't it working when I placed the function in the javascript window? You said it's `undefined`, but why is it `undefined` at that time?

Comment: Not a problem. Don't forget to accept answer if it was helpfull for you and welcome to SO ;)

Comment: Could you answer 1 last doubt? 

Why wasn't it working when I placed the function in the javascript window? You said it's `undefined`, but why is it `undefined` at that time?

Comment: This is because of closure. Don't forget to select `no wrap (head)` option at first select-box in jsFiddle. See demo - http://jsfiddle.net/antyrat/92WLE/4/

Comment: Ok this is working as well, but my js is an external file? how do I get it working for that? or can I get it working for that?

Comment: Include your script in `<head>` tag

Answer (score 0):

```
function value(object)
 {
alert('id= ' + object.id);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you might be firing the function when user loses focus on that input field.

Unless you are doing `obj.value.toUpperCase();` why do you want to fire the same function on each input field?

Anyways as @antyrat said `this` would give you the DOM element and you can pick `value` from it.

```
 function getValue(obj){
 obj.value=obj.value.toUpperCase();
 }
```

this would make all for of your input fields to `upper case` as user keeps moving ahead.

Comment: I have 2 forms with the same fields, I want to send the values of these fields to a javascript function to validate the value the user has enetered, so I want to write this in one function instead of 2. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function getValue(obj) {
        var id = obj.id;
        var value = obj.value;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can get the textbox id

```
<input type="text" id="myHeader" onblur="getValue(this.id)" /> <!-- instead of getValue(this) -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getValue(id) {
        alert(id);  // Display the id of the textbox
    }
</script>
```

Hope it will help you.